# Basic Highcharts Bubble Drilldown

Tags: highcharts, drilldown, bubble-chart

I'm new at Highcharts.  I'm trying to create a Drilldown Bubble Chart.

I took the basic column drilldown as a starting point,

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/

```
chart: {
  type: 'column'
},
title: {
  text: 'Basic drilldown'
},
xAxis: {
  type: 'category'
},

legend: {
  enabled: false
},

plotOptions: {
  series: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
},

series: [{
  name: 'Things',
  colorByPoint: true,
  data: [{
    name: 'Animals',
    y: 5,
    drilldown: 'animals'
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    y: 2,
    drilldown: 'fruits'
  }, {
    name: 'Cars',
    y: 4,
    drilldown: 'cars'
  }]
}],
drilldown: {
  series: [{
    id: 'animals',
    data: [
      ['Cats', 4],
      ['Dogs', 2],
      ['Cows', 1],
      ['Sheep', 2],
      ['Pigs', 1]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'fruits',
    data: [
      ['Apples', 4],
      ['Oranges', 2]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'cars',
    data: [
      ['Toyota', 4],
      ['Opel', 2],
      ['Volkswagen', 2]
    ]
  }]
}
```

and edited it a bit, to get this,

http://jsfiddle.net/Slate_Shannon/kdwa9x7v/1/

```
$(function() {

$('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
  type: 'bubble'
},
title: {
  text: 'Basic drilldown'
},
xAxis: {
  type: 'linear'
},

legend: {
  enabled: false
},

plotOptions: {
  series: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
},

series: [{
  name: 'Things',
  colorByPoint: true,
  data: [{
    name: 'Animals',
    x: 4,
    y: 5,
    z: 10,
    drilldown: 'animals'
  }, {
    name: 'Fruits',
    x: 14,
    y: 20,
    z: 20,
    drilldown: 'fruits'
  }, {
    name: 'Cars',
    x: 8,
    y: 9,
    z: 7,
    drilldown: 'cars'
  }]
}],
drilldown: {
  series: [{
    id: 'animals',
    data: [
      ['Cats', x: 5, y: 9, z: 7],
      ['Dogs', x: 8, y: 8, z: 9],
      ['Cows', x: 1, y: 5, z: 2],
      ['Sheep', x: 4, y: 7, z: 2],
      ['Pigs', x: 4, y: 5, z: 7]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'fruits',
    data: [
      ['Apples', x: 2, y: 9, z: 6],
      ['Oranges', x: 6, y: 5, z: 1]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'cars',
    data: [
      ['Toyota', x: 2, y: 8, z: 7],
      ['Opel', x: 8, y: 2, z: 4],
      ['Volkswagen', x: 4, y: 4, z: 4]
    ]
  }]
}
});
});
```

All I did was

- change the chart type to "bubble",
- add the x and z data,
- change the xaxis to "linear"

And it doesn't work.

Can you see the problem?

Thanks much!

Good day.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of your drilldown data is incorrect, as hinted to in console. Currently you have:

```
data: [
    ['Cats', x: 5, y: 9, z:7],
    ['Dogs', x: 8, y: 8, z:9],
    // ...
]
```

This is half way between an array declaration and a object declaration. I'd suggest switching to each item being an object, like this:

```
data: [
    { name: 'Cats', x: 5, y: 9, z:7 },
    { name: 'Dogs', x: 8, y: 8, z:9 },
    // ...
]
```

Secondly, you haven't included the required Highcharts-more module which includes the bubble chart type. You can do that like this:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ondkloss/kdwa9x7v/2/) for a basic example of how it can work.

Comment: Thanks!  That's great.